# Object class with virtual members or not?

Tags: c#, .net, oop

Let say I created a SomeObject class which has 100 properties or members like this,

```
Public Class SomeObject
{
  Public string Property1 {get; set;}
  Public string Property2 {get; set;}
  Public string Property3 {get; set;}
  Public string Property4 {get; set;}
  .... so on
  Public string Property100 {get; set;}
}
```

Now on some methods I am populating 2,3 properties and passing object and somewhere in code I am sending 50 out of 50.

**Would it be any good if I change these properties into virtual properties in this case ?**

EDIT:

Only thing I need to know is, If I pass above object like this to a method,

```
SomeObject so1 = new SomeObject();
so1.Property1 = "something";
so1.Property2 = "something";
so1.Property3 = "something";

MethodA(so1);
```

Now somewhere else in project I am doing this,

```
SomeObject so2 = new SomeObject();
so1.Property1 = "something";
so1.Property2 = "something";
so1.Property3 = "something";
....
so1.Property100 = "something";
MethodB(so2);
```

Is there any wrong with this approach :)

Edit 2:

Why i said I want to make properties virtual ? Because I was going through ASP.NET MVC training on Microsoft Virtual Training academy and somewhere in 6 hours videos guy said we will make few properties virtual as they didn't needed them everytime - "MOST Likely I understood it wrong and THOUGHT that virtual properties maybe something "ON DEMAND" objects"

So it's my fault I believe, I will go thorugh videos again at some point.

Comment: we are going to need a sample of your usage code in order to answer.

Comment: Ummm, thank you for your comment, I am just thinking this in a general case scenario, not sure how can i get usage code for you sir ?

Comment: Virtual allows you to override behavior in derived class. Nothing more. Car class still will have 50 properties

Comment: Are you populating them in your `Car` object, or a derived type?

Comment: if you have 100 properties you should reconsider your design.for example are you sure you don't need an array ?

Comment: @Selman22 really :S ? are we not talking about OOP here, as far as I understand it's about creating objects and there properties.... I might be wrong so guide me if I am, thanks :)

Comment: I'm looking at the cars in the car park, I can't decide what thier `Property1` is. You need to name your properties after a property of the the class they describe. Then your question will make more sense, and so will your design.

Comment: not an answer, just a suggestion.and I'm still trying to understand why do you think making the properties _virtual_ is relevant here...

Comment: @Selman22 please see Edit 2 for why I thought virtual properties might help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**NOTE** - Based on the comments above you are probably looking for [an array](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288453%28v=vs.71%29.aspx), [a generic (such as a list)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379564%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), [a dictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or you may even want to implement a [property bag](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12282/Implementing-a-PropertyBag-in-C). The rest of this answer explains when you would use the keyword `virtual`.

---

The primary purpose of declaring something as `virtual` is so you can write a basic implementation and then allow subclasses to provide specific implementations. Take the following as an example:

```
public class Car {
    public virtual string Make {
        get { return "Generic Make"; }
    }
}

public class Camaro : Car {
    public override string Make {
        get { return "Chevy"; }
    }
}
```

Now the specific implementation returns "Chevy" but if a developer forgets to override that it will just return "Generic Make".

There are (at least) two alternatives here:

1. Use the `new` keyword to hide the base class implementation:

   ```
   public class Car {
       public string Make {
           get { return "Generic Make"; }
       }
   }

   public class Camaro : Car {
       public new string Make {
           get { return "Chevy"; }
       }
   }
   ```

   The only issue with this is you have to cast as the subclass type in order to get the specific implementation. In other words, if you have a `Car` object you will always get "Generic Make" as the make for that car. You would have to cast as a `Camaro` in order to get the make of "Chevy" back!
2. The other option is to use a protected property in the base class, then that gets set in the subclass. This looks like:

   ```
   public class Car {
       protected string _carMake = "Generic Make";
       public string Make {
           get { return _carMake; }
       }
   }

   public class Camaro : Car {
       public Camaro() : base() {
           _carMake = "Chevy";
       }
   }
   ```

   Now using the `Make` property on the base class will return the appropriate value (generic vs chevy).

There are probably lots of good resources available online for learning about classes, inheritance and overriding behavior. Hopefully this at least gets you started!

Comment: Is there a reason to use a `PropertyBag` in favour of `ExpandoObject`? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: @Gusdor That could work as well! I was basically trying to say that storing 100 distinct named properties doesn't really make sense - arrays or really any generic would make more sense.

Comment: I agree entirely :) just wanted to make sure i wasn't missing any known performance or framework support issues.

Answer (score 3):

Declare a method or property as [`virtual`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9fkccyh4.aspx) if you anticipate that inheritors of a class will `override` a member or instead, use the inherited implementation.

---

Any class that has 100 properties enumerated `Property1` to `Property100` is poorly designed. This characteristic has no bearing on whether those properties should be declared with the `virtual` keyword.